# PSOC 4 Bootloader will not work when P4[0] and P4[1] Connected to I2C bus

Tags: i2c, bootloader, error, isp, psoc

I have been desparately juggling the pin allocations on this project in the hope of freeing up the VREF pin, and thought I had managed to do so.
Previously my system was successfully transmitting over the I2C Bus but when I move the SCL and SCA to pins 20 and 21 respectively the bootloader comes up with the message
"The bootloader reported error 'Packet data invalid: the packet sent to the bootloader does not conform to the required packet format, see the Bootloader section in the System Reference Guild for the correct format'."

The strange thing is that when I unplug these 2 wires the bootloader works as normal.
If I bootload the application and then connect the wires the system does not communicate over the I2C bus.
If I can get this to work it will make such a huge difference to my project. Does anyone know what is going on here?  Can I just not use these pins?

Comment: Making sure I understand: those pins don't work for bootloading and also don't work when the application is running?

Comment: Also, are you able to get a look at the waveforms on those pins during bootloading? Are you sure that you have proper pullup resistance etc?

Comment: One more: your IDE is Creator and you are using it to configure the inputs?

Comment: So I have since been able to get the I2C Bus to communicate with the rest of the system after power cycling but have found that it stops transmitting after a seemingly random number of bytes are passed. 
Yes, I am using creator.

Comment: OK, so all your connections must be correct for it to work at all. Does a slower I2C clock speed help at all?

Comment: It's working, I think the issue is that the bootloader is trying to use UART while the other devices on the I2C bus are subject to pullup resistors and a source of current fan out